# How do i join on null in two table in sql? inner join, left,right,full n cross join -- Interview Question Tech Mahindra

Tags: join, null

Create table TechM
(
id int
)
;

select * from TechM
insert into TechM values (1),
(1),
(1),
(2),
(3),
(null)
;

Create table TechN
(
id int
)
;

select * from TechN
insert into TechN values (1),
(1),
(2),
(2),
(2),
(2),
(null),
(4),
(5),
(null)
;

Comment: Please place `code` in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Each NULL is considered to be a different value, So In this case count will be as below

```
Left join -- 12
Right join -- 14
Full join --16
Cross join -- t1*t2 = 6*10 = 60
```

you can see the count/query on below link in detail :
[check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f1b36e43193534b11d02eee622f376b5)

These type of question is commonly asked in interview.